# Getting a new series conditional on some rows being present in Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, panel

I did not know of an easier thing to call what I am trying to do.  Edits welcome.  Here is what I want to do.

I have store, date, and product indices and a column called price.

I have two unique products 1 and 2.

But for each store, I don't have an observation for every date, and for every date, I don't have both products necessarily.

I want to create a series for each store that is indexed by dates only when  when both products are present.  The reason is because I want the value of the series to be product 1 price / product 2 price.

This is highly unbalanced panel, and I did a horrible workaround about 75 lines of code, so I appreciate any tips.  This will be very useful in the future.

Data looks like below.

```
   weeknum Location_Id Item_Id averageprice 
70  201138   8501       1          0.129642   
71  201138   8501       2          0.188274    
72  201138   8502       1          0.129642    
73  201139   8504       1          0.129642
```

Expected output in this simple case would be:

```
             weeknum   Location_Id   averageprice 
    ?        201138       8501     0.129642/0.188274
```

Since that is the only one with every requirement met.

Comment: please post data and expected output, plus your current code, it sounds doable but at the moment it is a little hypothetical until I see some real info

Comment: I'm not sure I would post this as an answer as it's a little too f*cked up even for me: `df.loc[df.Location_Id.isin(df.groupby('Location_Id')['Item_Id'].unique().apply(lambda x: len(x)> 1).replace(False,NaN).dropna().index), 'average_item_price'] = df['averageprice']/df['averageprice'].shift()`

Comment: To Ed:      df.loc[df.Location_Id.isin(df.groupby('Location_Id')['Item_Id'].unique().apply(‌​lambda x: len(x)> 1).replace(False,NaN).dropna().index), 'average_item_price'] = df['averageprice']/df['averageprice'].shift()
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be join on the two subFrames (but perhaps there is a cleaner pivoty way):

```
In [11]: res = pd.merge(df[df['Item_Id'] == 1], df[df['Item_Id'] == 2],
                        on=['weeknum', 'Location_Id'])

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
   weeknum  Location_Id  Item_Id_x  averageprice_x  Item_Id_y  averageprice_y
0   201138         8501          1        0.129642          2        0.188274
```

Now you can divide those two columns in the result:

```
In [13]: res['price'] = res['averageprice_x'] / res['averageprice_y']

In [14]: res
Out[14]:
   weeknum  Location_Id  Item_Id_x  averageprice_x  Item_Id_y  averageprice_y     price
0   201138         8501          1        0.129642          2        0.188274  0.688582
```

Answer (score 1):

Example data similar to yours:

```
   weeknum  loc_id  item_id  avg_price
0        1       8        1          8
1        1       8        2          9
2        1       9        1         10
3        2      10        1         11
```

First create a date mask that gets you the correct dates:

```
df_group = df.groupby(['loc_id', 'weeknum'])
df = df.join(df_group.item_id.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()) == 2), on = ['loc_id', 'weeknum'], r_suffix = '_r')

   weeknum  loc_id  item_id  avg_price item_id_r
0        1       8        1          8      True
1        1       8        2          9      True
2        1       9        1         10     False
3        2      10        1         11     False
```

This give yous a boolean mask for groupby of each store for each date where there are exactly two unique `Item_Id` present.  From this you can now apply the function that concatenates your prices:

```
df[df.item_id_r].groupby(['loc_id','weeknum']).avg_price.apply(lambda x: '/'.join([str(y) for y in x]))

loc_id  weeknum
8       1          8,9
```

It's a bit verbose and lots of lambdas but it will get you started and you can refactor to make faster and/or more concise if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your full dataset is called TILPS. Then you might try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from __future__ import division

# Get list of unique dates present in TILPS 
datelist = list(TILPS.ix[:, 'datetime'].unique())

# Get list of unique stores present in TILPS
storelist = list(TILPS.ix[:, 'store'].unique())

# For a given date, extract relative price
def dateLevel(daterow):
    price1 = int(daterow.loc[(daterow['Item_id']==1), 'averageprice'].unique())
    price2 = int(daterow.loc[(daterow['Item_id']==2), 'averageprice'].unique())
    return pd.DataFrame(pd.Series({'relprice' : price1/price2}))


# For each store, extract relative price for each date
def storeLevel(group, datelist): 
    info = {d: for d in datelist} 
    exist = group.loc[group['datetime'].isin(datelist), ['weeknum', 'locid']]     
    exist_gr = exist.groupy('datetime')
    relprices = exist_gr.apply(dateLevel)

    # Merge relprices with exist on INDEX. 
    exist.merge(relprices, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    return exist

# Group TILPS by store
gr_store = TILPS.groupby('store') 
fn = lambda x: storeLevel(x, datelist)
output = gr_store.apply(fn)

# Peek at output
print output.head(30)
```